# Trouble with turning .txt file into lists

Tags: python, list

In a project I am doing I am storing the lists in a .txt file in order to save space in my actual code. I can turn each line into a separate list but I need to turn multiple lines into one list where each letter is a different element. I would appreciate any help I can get. The program I wrote is as follows:

```
lst = open('listvariables.txt', 'r')
data = lst.readlines()

for line in data:
    words = line.split()
    print(words)
```

Here is a part of the .txt file I am using:

```
; 1

wwwwwwwwwww
wwwwswwwwww
wwwsswwwssw
wwskssssssw
wssspkswssw
wwwskwwwssw
wwwsswggssw
wwwswwgwsww
wwsssssswww
wwssssswwww
wwwwwwwwwww

; 2

wwwwwwwww
wwwwwsgsw
wwwwskgsw
wwwsksssw
wwskpswww
wsksswwww
wggswwwww
wssswwwww
wwwwwwwww
```

If someone could make the program print out two lists that would be great.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show in it the desired contents of the lists created from the text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load the whole file and turn it into a char-list like:

```
with open('listvariables.txt', 'r') as f    
    your_list = list(f.read())
```

I'm not sure why you want to do it, tho. You can iterate over string the same way you can iterate over a list - the only advantage is that list is a mutable object but you wouldn't want to do complex changes to it, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want each character in a string to be an element of the final list you should use

```
myList = list(myString)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly this should work:

```
with open('listvariables.txt', 'r') as my_file:
    my_list = [list(line) for line in my_file.read().splitlines()]
```